# How can I find the pixel art image out of thousands real images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

If there is a folder that contains the images, there are some of the images that are pixel art images and some of the images that are normal image, Check the following screenshot;

[image]

The last three images (8,9,10) are the normal images and the rest are the pixel art image. How can I distinguish if any image is a pixel art image? is there any method?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use a TensorFlow image classifier, please take a look at tensorflow.org

Comment: I had to zoom the image to find the difference myself. You can try analyzing each of these images in the Fourier domain and look for differences in the respective spectrum

Comment: For the classifier, I need to make two classes pixel art and no pixel art, for training the model. I need to create the data where I have to put the pixel art and no pixel art image, Why would I do this much work? There must be any unsupervised method.

Comment: @jeru luke, do you have any link or any reference? Please help me with this.

Comment: @TariqHussainDahri https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/dbc/tutorial_py_fourier_transform.html

Comment: Can you share these images one by one rather than all in one screenshot?

Comment: Check, I have uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that pixel art images contain lots of horizontal and vertical edges while regular images typically do not (or contain fewer of these lines). [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) can be used for the image processing. Edge detection can be performed via [`cv2.Canny`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de) and the lines can be detected via [`cv2.HoughLines`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a). This provides the angles of the detected lines and one can count the number of lines that have an angle close to `0`, `90` or `180` degrees. For the pixel art images this count will be much higher than for regular images. Then you can either apply a manual threshold or use a [clustering algorithm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods) to separate the images into two groups (pixel art and regular).

The code below covers the line counting procedure for the example images of the OP. It also contains some example code for the clustering, however, there are too few examples images for the clustering to work well. Of course, you can play with the parameters for `cv2.Canny` and `cv2.HoughLines` as well as the margin used to generate `regions` (currently `+/-1`) in order to find a setting that works best for a larger set of test images (which must be manually labeled beforehand).

```py
from math import pi
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


def count_number_of_hv_lines(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 5, 50, 50)  # remove noise (if any)
    img = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 150)
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(img, rho=1, theta=pi/180/10, threshold=50)
    if lines is None:
        return 0
    angles = lines.squeeze()[:,1] * 180/pi
    regions = [(x-1, x+1) for x in (0, 90, 180)]
    return sum(np.logical_and(l <= angles, angles <= u).sum() for l, u in regions)


n_lines_dict = {
    path.name: count_number_of_hv_lines(cv2.imread(f'{path!s}'))
    for path in Path('.').glob('*.jpg')
}
paths = np.array([*n_lines_dict.keys()])
n_lines = np.array([*n_lines_dict.values()])
pprint(n_lines_dict)

clustering = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
labels = clustering.fit_predict(np.array(n_lines)[:,None])
cluster_avg_n_lines = [n_lines[~labels.astype(bool)].mean(), n_lines[labels.astype(bool)].mean()]
pixel_art_label = np.argmax(cluster_avg_n_lines)
label_dict = {pixel_art_label: 'pixel', (pixel_art_label+1)%2: 'regular'}
labels = [label_dict[label] for label in labels]

for path, label in sorted(zip(paths, labels)):
    print(f'{path!s}: {label}')
```

The following is the content of the `n_lines_dict`:

```py
{'01.jpg': 442,
 '03.jpg': 221,
 '04.jpg': 214,
 '05.jpg': 278,
 '06.jpg': 96,
 '07.jpg': 253,
 '09.jpg': 29,
 '10.jpg': 2}
```

Another option would be to [detect horizontal and vertical lines](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/dd7/tutorial_morph_lines_detection.html) directly as masks and then use the integrated intensity of these masks (relative to the image size) as an indicator for pixel art images; larger intensity would mean more horizontal/vertical lines and thus higher probability to be pixel art.

Comment: Thank you so much, everything seem to be logical to me. Let me try it.